# Adding QueryParameters node to rdl XML

Tags: xml, powershell, ssrs-2008, powershell-2.0

I have an rdl that I have loaded into a Powershell xml variable. I want to add a query parameter to each of the data sets in the report, but I find that I first have to check to see if the data set has any query parameters first.

If a data set does not have any query parameters then it does not have a QueryParameters node to call AppendChild() on.

My rdl is loaded into a variable called $target. I can get all of the DataSet that don't have a QueryParameters node into a variable called $nodes. My problem is that most tutorials I see online seem to function as though $nodes contains a collection of pointers back to the actual nodes in my $target variable. But after I update $nodes to add the QueryParameters node, I then re-examine my $target variable and I don't see it getting updated.

So the question is, if I have a collection of nodes such that the path is not a straight line reachable via dot syntax, how can I update one member of that collection in a way that updates parent variables xml?

Below is the code I already have.

```
# Load the rdl
[xml]$target = New-Object System.XML.XMLDocument
$target.Load(<Path-to-rdl>)

$ns = @{r='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition';rd='http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner'}


$nsmgr = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($target.NameTable)
$nsmgr.AddNameSpace("r",$ns.r)
$nsmgr.AddNameSpace("rd",$ns.rd)

# Grab the query nodes    
$nodes = $target.SelectNodes("//r:DataSet/r:Query",$nsmgr)


# Attempt to load the QueryParameters node. If $p is $NULL I know it didn't have one.
$nodes | %{
        $p = $_.SelectSingleNode("./r:QueryParameters",$nsmgr)
        IF($p -eq $NULL){
          $p = $target.CreateElement("QueryParameters")
          # Many tutorials assume $_ here points back to xml in my $target variable
          $_.AppendChild($p) 
        } 
    }

$nodes = $NULL

$nodes = $target.SelectNodes("//r:DataSet/r:Query",$nsmgr)

$nodes | %{
        $p = $_.SelectSingleNode("./r:QueryParameters",$nsmgr)
        # But after I reload the nodes from $target some still don't have the
        # QueryParameters node I appended earlier.
        IF($p -eq $NULL){
          "NULL" 
        } ELSE {"NOT NULL"}
    }
```

How can I make sure $target gets updated with the new QueryParameters node so that when I write it back out to disk it will be there?

This is also a problem I need to solve for my next step. If I can't get this updated then I also won't be able to add the new QueryParameter node to each DataSet.

Thanks, Bill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest problem I was having is that Powershell interprets empty nodes as System.String instead of XML.XMLElement. The code that appended the QueryParameters node was succeeding and adding it to the document. But since it gets interpreted as a string instead of an element it doesn't take append properly and attempting to check for it's presence using normal Powershell XML syntax fails.

Instead if you have an empty node you have find it using $xml.Parent.item("EmptyNodeName")

This will return an actual XML.XMLElement that has the AppendChild() method.